# Google Cloud Console Language Interface

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-console-developer

I have a problem with the language interface of page console.cloud.google.com
My language in the account is Vietnamese and English. But now it was changed to this language. I don't know to change it back to English. Can somebody help me with this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1. Click the menu button (one with 3 vertical dots) in the top right hand side corner, left of your profile image.
2. Choose `Preferences`, which is the first item in the menu overlay. You will be now taken to the `User Preferences` page.
3. You will see 3 items in the left hand side list, the second one is `Language & Region`. Click on this second item.
4. You will see the page where you can choose language, date, time and number formats. The first drop-down in this page is `Language` selection. Choose your desired language from this list.
5. After selecting the language, hit the `Save` button, which is the only blue colored button on this page.

Comment: Does not work for documentation. Since the French translation is of poor quality, I'm forced to add `?hl=en` for every webpage I visit. Pretty anoying.

Answer (score 0):

First, click on the 3dots, go to preferences, then Language & Region :

[image]

[image]